# Bottom Overflowed in Chrome / Desktop Resolution in Flutter

Tags: flutter

when i add container / listview in mobile resolution there is no bottom overflowed problem. (and the content can still be scrolled).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG5U1.jpg)

however when i add container in chrome/desktop resolution
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ztV7.jpg)

I've been looking for ways to solve this problem on the internet, such as adding

```
Expanded()
```

or

```
 resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false
```

and so on.

but still can't solve this problem.
here's my code:
`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyDesktopBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyDesktopBody({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('D E S K T O P'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            // First Column
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  // Youtube Video
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 250,
                        color: Colors.redAccent,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  // Comment Section & Recommended Videos
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 8,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: 8,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.black54,
                              height: 120,
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),

            // Second Column
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                width: 200,
                color: Colors.black54,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

change the first `Column` into a `Listview` and remove the second `Expanded` and it should work properly

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  class MyDesktopBody extends StatelessWidget {
    const MyDesktopBody({super.key});

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('D E S K T O P'),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              // First Column
              Expanded(
                child: ListView( //<---- here
                  children: [
                    // Youtube Video
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                        child: Container(
                          height: 20,
                          color: Colors.redAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    // Comment Section & Recommended Videos 
                    ListView.builder( //<--here
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: 8,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.black54,
                              height: 120,
                            ),
                          );
                        })
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              // Second Column
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  width: 200,
                  color: Colors.black54,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```